# Open a partial view in a dialog, execute a controller action and then close

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a Cases model with Index, Edit, Create, and Details views. I have a Cases controller. While a user is in the Edit view of Cases I want them to be able to click a button that opens a jQuery dialog with a partial view to add Complaint Codes to the case. Here is the partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<cummins_db.Models.ComplaintCode>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Case Complaint Codes";
}

<h2>Select a complaint code</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            Complaint Code Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Complaint Type
        </th>
    </tr>

@try
    {
    foreach (var item in Model)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "SelectForCase", new { id = item.ComplaintCodeID})
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComplaintCodeName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComplaintType)
        </td>
    </tr>
        }
    }
catch
{
}

</table>
```

The user can select data presented in the partial view list and add it as a many to many relation to the edit record they have open. 
I am using this controller method from the partial view to add the MTM record.

```
public void SelectForCase(int id)
        {
        int cid;
        cid = casesid;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            CaseComplaint c = new CaseComplaint
            {
                CasesID = cid,
                ComplaintCodeID = id
            };
            db.CaseComplaints.Add(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that after this action fires, the jQuery modal dialog and the Edit view closes.
I just want to close the jQuery dialog and allow the user to continue the Edit of the Case record.

The partial view is doing what it needs to do but I need to keep the Edit view open.

This is the jQuery that gets called from the Edit view actionlink and opens the partial view in a dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addComplaintLink').button();

    $('#AddComplaintDialog').dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons:
        {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $('.addComplaintLink').click(function () {
        linkObj = $(this);
        var dialogDiv = $('#AddComplaintDialog');
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function(data) {
            dialogDiv.html(data);
        //open dialog
        dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ryan- Add more code of your controller and the entire related View so we can understand your case.

Comment: @Tohid Thanks for your time. I added more info. Let me know if that is enough or if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you need to use `AJAX` in your partial.

So instead of using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "SelectForCase", new { id = item.ComplaintCodeID})
```

try:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("linkText", "SelectForCase", new { id = item.ComplaintCodeID},
                   new AjaxOptions() {...})
```

[Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493139]

or try update your model by using jQuery.Ajax, not by posting back the whole view.

Comment: That makes sense. I will take a stab at it and post back here with the results.